# Triggering a React effect periodically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following simple React component with an effect that fetches some data and saves it to the component state:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("data.json");
      setData(await res.json());
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

What is the right way to set this effect to run periodically, say every minute?

Is it as easy as replacing `fetchData()` with `setInterval(fetchData, 60)` or are there other React-specific considerations I should be thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it as easy as replacing fetchData() with setInterval(fetchData, 60)

Yes.

Just make sure to do `clearInterval` (return of `useEffect()`) when component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("data.json");
    setData(await res.json());
  };

  const t = setInterval(fetchData, 60000);

  return () => clearInterval(t); // clear
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Are there other React-specific considerations I should be thinking of?

Just for the completeness of [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58428398/7882470), you [should consider memoizing](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) the component's children, or it will rerender them on each interval:

```
//                         v Notice the children
function MyComponent({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('data.json');
      setData(await res.json());
    };

    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 60000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


//            v Causes children to re-render every interval
  return <>{children}</>;
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Possible case:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Child />
</MyComponent>
```

Solution:

```
// Possible Child
function Child = () => <></>

//                     v Memoization using shallow comparison
export default React.memo(Child);
```